# Appcelerator - iOS : Use launch screen storyboard only for iPhone?

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

It's possible to use the **launch screen storyboard** only for iPhone?

```
<enable-launch-screen-storyboard>true</enable-launch-screen-storyboard>
```

I started using this feature with iPhone X, and for all the iPhone's models it's ok. But i don't want to support iPad Pro (for now).

Before the activation of the *enable-launch-screen-storyboard* functionality it was enough to not put the iPad Pro splash-screen to disable the iPad Pro support.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only differ now between iPhone and iPad